# Alloy - comparing in first order logic

Tags: alloy, first-order-logic

How does one compare the equality of functions in Alloy?  Something like:

```
--[(All x)(Exists y)[R(x,y)] 
-- and (All x)(All y)[R(x,y) -> R(y,x)]] 
-- = 
-- (All x)[R(x,x)] and 

assert checkEquality{
    ( all m: Model, x:m.A| some y:m.A | (y in x.(m.R)) ) and
    ( all m: Model, x:m.A, y:m.A | (y in x.(m.R) -> x in y.(m.R)) ) =
    ( all m: Model, x:m.A | (x in x.(m.R))
}
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what your question is.  Is the initial comment complete, or was some text lost at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elementary version. Guessing by the '(All x)(All y)[R(x,y) -> R(y,x)]]' part, you've probably thought of something more special; in that case, please specify your question further.

```
sig Value {}

pred p1 [x, y: Value] {
    // ...
}

pred p2 [x, y: Value] {
    // ...    
}

assert equ_pred {
    all x, y: Value | p1 [x, y] <=> p2 [x, y]
}

check equ_pred
```